# Access specifiers in class

Tags: class, copy-constructor

I know that, normally, 'objects' of a class cannot access the private members. But in the function definition of a copy constructor, you use objects to access the private members members. How come?
eg:-

```
class Sample {int i,j;
 public: 
 Sample(int a, int b)
 {i=a;j=b;}
 Sample(Sample &S)
 {j=s.j;i=s.i;}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the same class. A different *instance*, but the same class.

`private` means that the member is only visible within the class - including other instances.

Comment: It's still not clear...I'm asking how can you use "s.j", where 's' is the class object and 'j' is a private data member, given the stipulation that objects cannot access private members.

Comment: @vpp - That's not the stipulation. `private` means a member is only accessible inside the declaring _class_. Another object, of the _same_ class can access the private members of either class.

Comment: @Oded- "class sample {int i;}; sample s ". Now if you use 's.i' outside the class you get an error but you don't get an error if you use it inside the class,is this so?

Comment: @vpp - Yes. It will be accessible from any _instance_ of the class.